# Numbering each value in a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'event_name': ['fulham','fulham','fulham','fulham','fulham','fulham'],
                      'batfast_id': ['bfs1', 'bfs1', 'bfs1', 'bfs1', 'bfs1', 'bfs1'],
                      'session_no': [1,1,1,1,1,1],
                      'overs': [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                      'deliveries_faced': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                      'length/type': ['ES_LS_Y','ES_LS_Y','S_S_Y','ES_OS_Y','ES_LS_Y','ES_LS_Y']}, columns=['event_name', 'batfast_id','session_no','overs', 'deliveries_faced','length/type'])
df = df.set_index(['event_name', 'batfast_id','session_no','overs', 'deliveries_faced'],drop=True)
print(df)
```

There are 6 `deliveries_faced` in an over. I then produce a `sequence` column that gives the sequence of 6 `length/type` in each over using this code:

```
df['sequence'] = (df.groupby(["event_name", "batfast_id", "session_no", "overs"])["length/type"]
                       .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x)).loc[lambda x: x.str.count(",") == 5]

                   )
```

However I want to number each delivery in the `sequence`. eg `'ES_LS_Y1','ES_LS_Y2','S_S_Y3','ES_OS_Y4','ES_LS_Y5','ES_LS_Y6'` or something along those lines that uniquely numbers each delivery.

Comment: what is the expected output? I don't see why you need `groupby`

Answer (score 1):

You can try enumerating the x and then use the index in a format string, check the code below.

```
df['sequence'] = (df.groupby(["event_name", "batfast_id", "session_no", "overs"])["length/type"]
                   .apply(lambda x: ','.join(f'{val}_{i}' for i, val in enumerate(x)))
               )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I am looking for. It just needs `.loc[lambda x: x.str.count(",") == 5]` on the end so that only complete overs of 6 deliveries are counted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`:

```
out = df.groupby(level=df.index.names[:-1])['length/type'] \
        .apply(lambda x: ','.join(f"{v}{i}" for i, v in enumerate(x.tolist(), 1)))
print(out)

# Output:
                                                        length/type
event_name batfast_id session_no overs deliveries_faced            
fulham     bfs1       1          0     0                    ES_LS_Y
                                       1                    ES_LS_Y
                                       2                      S_S_Y
                                       3                    ES_OS_Y
                                       4                    ES_LS_Y
                                       5                    ES_LS_Y
```